# Bundle data is not updating in the activity passed from a notification in service, always populating the first bundle

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am handling push notification in my application using GCMIntentService. I am creating a status bar notification and navigating to an activity using pending Intent.

my Code for creating a notification is :

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String  title1, String desc, String soln, String date, String time) {
 int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("","@@##@@ notificatin"+title1+desc+soln+message);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,AppLog.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.REQUEST_FROM, "notification");
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.INFO_TITLE, title1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.INFO_DESC, desc);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.INFO_SOLUTION, soln);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.INFO_DATE, date);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Description.INFO_TIME, time);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  0,notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pIntent);
    Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notification.sound=uri;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And inside my AppLog.class I am handling it like :

```
 if(bundle!=null && bundle.containsKey(Description.REQUEST_FROM)){

        Log.i("","@@##@@ applog"+bundle);

    }
```

When the first notification is sent to the device data will be populated correctly in my AppLog Activity class. But onwards for all notifications it always show me the old bundle.

I tried everything but still the issue persist. Is there any issue with pending intents or notification created from services ?

Comment: hi... did you find any solution?.. i have same problem .

Comment: actually there is no solution for this. I have used SharedPreferences to transfer the data, because any how I was saving the data in the activity screen so I had saved them in the service and them read it from Activity.

Comment: i tried this and it is working..PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
                      notificationIntent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT which will not allow caching and you will bundle wat you set

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always passing a 0 value as the second parameter try and pass a random number.

```
Random r = new Random();
        int no = r.nextInt(999999);

     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,  no,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```